# Flutter How to import backendless_sdk messaging module?

Tags: flutter, backendless

I am following this article 
[How to Create a Chat App with Backendless SDK for Flutter](https://backendless.com/how-to-create-chat-app-with-flutter-sdk/)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:backendless_sdk/backendless_sdk.dart'; 
import 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart';
```

There is a error:

```
"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart'."
```

The modules.dart import is required for Backendless.Messaging, but without the import there is an error:

```
The getter 'Messaging' isn't defined for the type 'Backendless'.
```

```
  void initListeners() async {
    Channel channel = await Backendless.Messaging.subscribe("myChannel");
    channel.addMessageListener(onMessageReceived);
  }
```

pub spec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  backendless_sdk: ^1.1.8
```

How can I import the Messaging module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change from:

```
await Backendless.Messaging.subscribe
```

in to:

```
await Backendless.messaging.subscribe
                  ^
                  |
           small "m" here
```

## Versions

I checked `backendless_sdk: ^0.0.2` (from tutorial) and `backendless_sdk: ^1.1.8` (newest one), and in both cases this field was named `messaging` (lowercase).

## Class `Backendless`

`backendless_sdk-1.1.8/lib/src/backendless.dart`:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the article was written for a pre-release version of the SDK. The documentation uses lower-case "m": https://backendless.com/docs/flutter/pubsub_establish_subscription.html

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are missing the [installation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#adding-a-package-dependency-to-an-app) step.

- From the terminal: Run flutter pub get.

OR

- From Android Studio/IntelliJ: Click Packages get in the action ribbon
  at the top of pubspec.yaml.
- From VS Code: Click Get Packages located
  in right side of the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Remove `import 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart';`

Comment: Don't import implementation files from another package. Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist

Comment: import 'package:backendless_sdk/src/modules/modules.dart' is required for Backendless.Messaging.subscribe("myChannel");

Comment: There is not reference about it on https://pub.dev/packages/backendless_sdk, no even in the article you are following.

Comment: This is a link to the source code for the article: https://github.com/4lfant/messaging_app/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: The article that is using `backendless_sdk: ^0.0.2` from May 13, 2019, and you are using `backendless_sdk: ^1.1.8`, please use as a reference https://pub.dev/documentation/backendless_sdk/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any references to `modules.dart` in the article you mentioned. You need to import backendless_sdk and also include the socket.io dependency:

```
dependencies {
   implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') { 
     // excluding org.json which is provided by Android 
     exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json' 
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a link to the source code for the article: github.com/4lfant/messaging_app/blob/master/lib/main.dart